# String to sort index of authors generated with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx

I have an index of cited authors generated with `biblatex` and `imakeidx`. How can I have this index sorted by the `sortkey` field in the `bib`-file, if defined.

For indexing titles there is a `indexsorttitle` field (biblatex manual p. 26), but there is no parallel for authors.

My idea was to use the `sortstring@printed name` syntax in the `\index` commend via the `bibmacro`, but I dont know how to make this work. Something like `\iffieldundef{sortkey}{}{\thefield{sortkey}@}` inserted in the macro, perhaps?

In the example below, al-Xalil should be sorted after Brutus in the index.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[indexing=cite]{biblatex}


\makeindex[title=Index of Authors, name=author]
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
    {\indexnames{labelname}}{}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[author]}
  {#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}



\begin{filecontents}{general.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Arabicname al-Xalil},
  year = {2001},
  sortkey = {xalil},
  title = {Alpha}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Alex Brutus},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}
}
\end{filecontents}  
\addbibresource{general.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{A01}
\cite{B02}

    \printindex[author]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accorindg to the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) the field `sortkey` is not written to the `.bbl` file and thus not available for use in the document (p. 27).

We will have to use another field, because I'm lazy I used `usera` below. One could of course create a new `indexsortname` field via a `.dbx` file.

Then we simply use as you yourself suggested

```
\renewbibmacro*{index:name}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{#1}
    {\iffieldundef{usera}{}{\thefield{usera}\actualoperator}\mkbibindexname{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[indexing=cite]{biblatex}

\makeindex[title=Index of Authors, name=author]
\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
    {\indexnames{labelname}}{}}

\renewbibmacro*{index:name}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{#1}
    {\iffieldundef{usera}{}{\thefield{usera}\actualoperator}\mkbibindexname{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[author]}
  {#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Arabicname al-Xalil},
  year = {2001},
  usera = {xalil},
  sortkey = {xalil},
  title = {Alpha}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Alex Brutus},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}
}
\end{filecontents}  
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{A01}
\cite{B02}

\printindex[author]
\end{document}
```

[image: index of MWE]

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution while using a name field (instead of `usera`). Would you know how to write the `index:name` macro so that it prints the name field into the index, e.g. with "last name, given name" (instead of `\thefield{usera}`)? Thanks

Comment: @ienissei The field `usera` here is only for sorting. It is not printed. The printing is done by `\mkbibindexname` and that is indeed applied to a name field (as you can see in the output). I'm not quite sure what you need. Can you give more details? (If necessary in a new question?)

Comment: Will ask a new question, as what I am asking might be achieved through other ways.